# React onChange handler is being called multiple times during page load

Tags: html, reactjs, state, jsx

We're trying to add a `onChange` handler to one of our custom components - namely, a `Checkbox` component (the only reason for it being a custom component is so that we can efficiently encapsulate the `intermediate` HTML attribute). It looks something like this:

```
<Checkbox
  id="select-all"
  onChange={this.handleSelectAllChange(ids)}
  indeterminate={isIndeterminate}
  checked={areVisibleItemsSelected}
  disabled={isDisabled}
/>
```

The handler function is structured somewhat like this:

```
handleSelectAllChange(ids) {
  // omitted code that filters on ids and produces newIds

  this.props.updateIds(newIds);
}
```

Where `this.props.updateIds` is a passed-down function that modifies the parent component's state.

The problem is that this function is called about 10 times during page load, which is not intended. I thought it was only called when the actual checkbox element is modified?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By declaring it like this `onChange={this.handleSelectAllChange(ids)}` the method call happens immediately at rendering the `CheckBox`. With ES6 you can avoid this by using

`onChange={() => this.handleSelectAllChange(ids)}`

This means you pass a new function which will call `handleSelectAllChange` on change.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue... I was able to fix the problem stopping the propagation of the event.
Add this in the function being called by your onChange event:

`e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: This answer just saved me a lot of time! I already spent over ~45mins trying to solve this bug. Thanks @rii

Comment: My pleasure @AdimVictor I am sure I probably spent several hours trying to figure that one out. I recall it being particularly painful.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the handler function like

```
<Checkbox
  id="select-all"
  onChange={this.handleSelectAllChange.bind(this,ids)}
  indeterminate={isIndeterminate}
  checked={areVisibleItemsSelected}
  disabled={isDisabled}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define onClick inside the element itself, and pass a pointer to the handler function:

```js
function Checkbox(props) {
  return (<input type="checkbox" value={props.value} key={props.value} 
    onClick={props.clickHandler} />); // actual onclick
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      boxes: ['1', '2', '3'],
    }
  }
  
  handleSelectAllChange(box) {
    console.log(box)
  }
  
  render() {
    const boxes = this.state.boxes.map((b,i) => 
     <Checkbox value={b} 
        clickHandler={this.handleSelectAllChange.bind(this, b)} // pass click handler
        key={i}/>
    );
    return (
      <div>
         {boxes}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, 
 document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.handleSelectAllChange(ids)` means call the function.
You should pass a **function object** to event handlers. e.g.`()=>{this.handleSelectAllChange(ids)}`